# Allow user to edit card information when processing recurring payment in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, recurring-billing

I am trying to implement recurring payment in Stripe. I also want to store card information and allow user to edit it. Because sometimes user may want to change card or edit card information. I want this edited/updated card information to be used to process recurring payment. I am using PHP(in Wordpress). Please share some guideline. Thank you.

Comment: To update cards you'd want to provide a membership dashboard or customer management area on your web site. This is not something that Stripe provides, so you'd want to build on your own (https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/updating-customer-cards), or use a 3rd party service or plugin to create this for you (many wordpress plugins include something like this)

Answer (score 0):

I created a plugin for this exactly, as well as checking Whether or not they are still valid subscribers, that way you may lock them out of content effectively. I coded it in php.